Best way to take a snapshot of a token like Marinade, Blaze etc does, what should be the best approach for that?
I have a create a Stake pool .I want to take a snapshot of the users and their holdings of the pool token like Marinade and Blaze does.What should be the best approach for that?
I am creating this tool in rust and Was thinking of using Helius APIs.
The approach in my mind is ,

I have the list of users who has staked and check their past holding.(But his won't include them who got the token by transfer or defi)
Check current holders and check their history (again flawed)
I got a vague answer of "we scan the whole blockchain", If it is good ,how to do that, like to start scanning it?

